# Unable to select item from Popup window listing - android

Tags: android, popupwindow, samsung-mobile, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I am using PopupWindow for selecting city.
I am able to select(click) item in Marshmallow but not able to select in JellyBean 4.3 (Samsung Galaxy S3)

Anybody know?

Comment: post your code here

Comment: unable to comment whole code, commenting by portions

Comment: I have method: private PopupWindow popupWindowCities() {}

Comment: ListView lv = (ListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.lvCities);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                Log.e("Selected City", cityList[position]);
            }
        });

Comment: popupWindow.setContentView(layout);
        popupWindow.setWidth(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        popupWindow.setHeight(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        popupWindow.setTouchable(true);
        popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);

Comment: return popupWindow;

Comment: Done! @AnkitaShah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add one line.

```
popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
```

It solves your problem.Enjoy :)